# What can be a possible algorithm for this combinatorics based program?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

So, this contest is already over.

I was trying to solve this problem: `http://codeforces.com/contest/554/problem/C`

I spent like 1 hour to solve this problem. What I thought was, fill the last `n` positions of the array with one ball of each kind. Then, in the remaining positions, find the permutations by calculating remaining places in array divided by balls of each kind - 1 (since one is fixed at last position). This will obviously miss out on a lot of test cases, since I don't consider cases when 2 largest numbers will be together in the end or 3 largest numbers will be there. Similarly, along with 4 numbers, other similar numbers might be there before them. But I mean, I am not able to think of a approach how should I solve this?

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Also, the contest has already ended, so no issues there. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am sorry, but asking for possible algorithms or pseudo-code is not meant for SO?

Comment: I didn't think so, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: Calculate result with [recurrent formula](http://i.imgur.com/BF7N9PE.png)

Comment: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18842 Editorial's out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hints

Consider the example given where we have 1,2,3,4 balls of each colour.

Place the first ball: 1 option.

Now consider placing the 2 balls of the next colour.  Place one at any position (2 choices - either before or after the first ball), then place the second at the end.

Now consider placing the 3 balls of the next colour.  Place two at any position C(1+2+2,2), and the last at the end.

Finally consider placing the 4 balls of the final colour.  Place three at any position C(1+2+3+3,3), and the last at the end.

This gives 1680 choices.